# MAMP Pro 5.1.1-terminates MySQL when quitting

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro, macos-mojave

I updated to Mac OS Mojave and started experiencing this. If I logout of my machine it quits all running apps. MySQL gets quit in the process. Never did before. The Apache and DNS services of MAMP do not quit. Just MySQL.

Mostly I don't bother with MAMP, it just runs. It starts when my machine starts at 7am EST and runs until shutdown at 11pm EST. I have clients that access my development sites. So people started complaining.

I have come to this conclusion that I cannot logout once my machine starts. Ever. Or MySQL quits and my sites are not accessible. I do have my user preference set to lock my screen after 1 hour of inactivity. That does not quit any apps. That works.

If for some reason I want to inspect the MAMP app for setup or config settings to dismiss it I must go to it's icon in the dock, right-click, and choose Hide.

If I want to leave my office and want my machine secure I have to let lock itself up after the prescribed amount of time. If I choose Sleep that too with quit MySQL.

I don't know if this is an issue I can fix by tweaking the settings of either the OS or MAMP or if this is a "bug" of somekind.

Thanks.

Duane Mitchell

Answer (score 2):

After updating Mac OS from 10.14.0 to 10.14.1 the issue has ceased to be a problem.